# how many chain of subsets are there

Tags: combinatorics

for the set $ A=\{1,2,...,n\} $ for each $0<k\leq n$ how many chains of subsets are there that satisfy the condition?

$$ A_1 \Delta_1 A_2 \Delta_2 ... \Delta_{k-1} A_k  \subseteq A$$

$$ \Delta_i \in \{ {\supseteq} , {\subseteq} \} $$

What I've gotten so far is for $k=1$ we have $2^n$ chains (since it's only $A_1$ and it can be any set)

And for $k=2$ we have $\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{k}2^k$ + $\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{k}(2^{(n-k)}-1)$ where first sum is for where $A_1$ is a superset of $A_2$ and the second one is for when $A_1$ is a subset of $A_2$

My question is, is there a formula for each $n$, $k$?

Comment: Please clarify the $\sum$ variable.

Comment: I think you only have to count the increasing chains, i.e. $A_1\subseteq \cdots\subseteq A_k$ because you can find any decreasing one by inverting the order. The only exceptions are the ones where all $A_i$ are equal. So if there are $N$ increasing chains, then there are $2N-2^n$ chain in total.

Comment: @M.Winter: My immediate understanding is that he's counting chains that may switch arbitrarily between increasing and decreasing, so long as any two neighbor elements are comparable.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Ah, I see. I assumed all $\Delta$ must be the same operator. OP should probably use indexed $\Delta_i\in\{\subseteq,\supseteq\}$ then.

Comment: @M.Winter: I suspect what he was really trying to write was $\Delta = (\supseteq)\cup(\subseteq)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we divide into cases according to the number of elements in $A_1$, we can write down a recurrence and find that you're looking for the bottom right element (or any of the corner elements, really; they'll be equal) of the exponentiated matrix

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
1 & \binom{1}{0} & \binom{2}0 & \cdots & \binom{n-1}0 & \binom{n}0 \\
\binom{n}{n-1} & 1 & \binom{2}{1} & \cdots & \binom{n-1}n & \binom{n}1 \\
\binom{n}{n-2} & \binom{n-1}{n-2} & 1 & \cdots & \binom{n-1}2 & \binom n2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
\binom n 1 & \binom{n-1}1 & \binom{n-2}1 & \cdots & 1 & \binom n{n-1} \\
\binom n 0 & \binom{n-1}0 & \binom{n-2}0 & \cdots & \binom 10 & 1
\end{pmatrix} ^ {\textstyle k+1} $$

I doubt there is any nice arithmetic-looking formula for that, but viewing it as matrix exponentiation would let you exploit tricks such as exponentiation-by-squaring to *compute* your number faster than step-by-step.

Comment: Interesting — I was thinking of the problem as walks of length $k$ along the edges of a cube, in which case adjacency matrix stuff might show up. Is that where your matrix is coming from? EDIT: oh but I don’t think mine is quite right... it would need to count edges etc along the walk.

Comment: Thanks, This is an interesting approach that I hadn't thought of. I'm still looking for a more straight-forward formula but so far this makes more sense than the way I was attacking the problem